# Getting Minimum and Maximum Date From a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the Minmum and Maximum Date from a column.
But i always i get result in Time format like 12.00.00 AM

Code Whicch i used for that is given below

```
    Dim Sheet12 As Worksheet
    Dim Mesh_Range As Range
   Set Sheet12 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA_SHEET")

   Sheet12.Activate


   Dim Min_Date As Date
   Dim Max_Date As Date

   Min_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("A"))
    Max_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
```

And also i attached column value as Image Which i tried.

Kindly help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance
By Suresh Vijayan
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gWwr.png)

Comment: What do you mean `i get result in Time format like 12.00.00 AM`?  The code you posted doesn't "show" anything.  Where do you "get" this value?  You're formulas will correctly place the min/max date/times into the variables you specified, assuming the dates in column `A` aren't stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

## Checking Your Dates

Running this procedure.  It will either correctly the correct Min/Max, *or* **if your dates are entered incorrectly**, it will show you the correct way to enter them:

```
Sub testDates()

    Dim Sheet12 As Worksheet
    Dim Min_Date As Date
    Dim Max_Date As Date

    Set Sheet12 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA_SHEET")

    Min_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheet12.Columns("A"))
    Max_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet12.Columns("A"))

    If Not IsDate(Min_Date) Or Min_Date < 10000 Then
        MsgBox "No dates found. Maybe it's incorrectly stored as text?" & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "The correct way to enter a date is one of these two ways:" & vbLf & _
            "   SHORT DATE FORMAT:  " & Format(Now(), "Short Date") & vbLf & _
            "   LONG DATE FORMAT:    " & Format(Now(), "Long Date")
    Else
        MsgBox "Dates Found!" & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Min: " & Min_Date & vbLf & "Max: " & Max_Date
    End If

End Sub
```

---

## Fixing Your Dates

Dates need to be entered in the format appropriate to your regional settings.  If you have a lot of incorrectly entered dates, you can "fix" them with this function:

```
Public Function DateFromText(str As String) As Date
    'converts text in D-MMM-YY format to a Date
    Dim strOut As String
    strOut = Split(str, "-")(1) & " " & Split(str, "-")(0) & " 20" & Split(str, "-")(2)
    If Not IsDate(strOut) Then Exit Function
    DateFromText = DateValue(strOut)
End Function
```

You can call the function from VBA, or directly on the worksheet like:

```
=DateFromText(A1)
```